# Как передать тип object в ObservebleCollection<T> где "T" один из 4 объектов. C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, usercontrol

Мне нужно в моем UserControl организовать DependencyProperty типом которого будет ObservebleCollection. Как мне в UserControl передать то самое "T" которое представляет собой один из четырех объектов-классов, таких например как User.
При вызове UserControl должно определится как он вызван и передать соответствующий тип объекта.

```
public partial class ContentViewer : UserControl
    {

    #region DP

    #region ItemsCollections DP

        public ObservableCollection<T> ItemsCollection 
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection <T>) GetValue (ItemsCollectionProperty); }
            set { SetValue (ItemsCollectionProperty, value);}
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsCollectionProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register ("ItemsCollection", typeof(ObservableCollection <T>),
                typeof(ContentViewer), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    #endregion

    #endregion


        public ContentViewer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainGrid.DataContext = this;
        }
    }
```

в данном случе "T" объект который может прийти в качастве параметра, таких объектов у меня 4, не хочу писать отдельно для каждого, решил через дженерик делать. Как мне в UserControl передать это "Т"

XAML

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row ="1"  Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <!-- DataGrid with Items -->
                    <Border Height="Auto" Width="400" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Chartreuse">
                        <DataGrid x:Name="ItemsGrid"
                                  Padding="3"
                                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                  HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Aquamarine"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsCollections, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                  SelectionChanged="ItemGrid_OnSelectionChanged">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn 
                                    Width="100"
                                    Binding="{Binding Path=Id}"
                                    Header="ID"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn
                                    Width="300"
                                    Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"
                                    Header="Name"/>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>

                        </DataGrid>
                    </Border>
```

Comment: есть нароботки? а то не совсем понятно пока

Comment: Вопрос в том, что в вашем XAML. Делаете ли вы привязку к `ItemsCollection`?

Comment: конечно же делаю

Answer (score 1):

Обычным решением вашей проблемы было бы объявить класс `ContentViewer` обобщённым по `T`:

```
public partial class ContentViewer<T> : UserControl
{
    public ObservableCollection<T> ItemsCollection
    {
        ...
```

В вашем случае, однако, проблема в том, что невозможно в XAML'е объявить generic-контрол, поддерживаются лишь контролы *конкретного* типа.

Поэтому ваш класс придётся разбить на части. Например, так:

```
public partial class ContentViewerBase : UserControl
{
    public ContentViewerBase()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainGrid.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

(и к нему тот же XAML).

В XAML'е вы уже можете привязываться к (несуществующей) коллекции, поскольку `Binding` обладает поздним связыванием. Коллекцию прикручиваем сверху:

```
class ContentViewerGeneric<T> : ContentViewerBase
{
    #region DP ItemsCollections
    public ObservableCollection<T> ItemsCollection
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<T>)GetValue(ItemsCollectionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsCollectionProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsCollectionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register (
            "ItemsCollection",
            typeof(ObservableCollection<T>),
            typeof(ContentViewerGeneric<T>));
    #endregion
}

class ContentViewerOfDouble : ContentViewerGeneric<double> { }
class ContentViewerOfString : ContentViewerGeneric<string> { }
```

и т. д.

Пользоваться можно лишь «конкретными» классами наподобие `ContentViewerOfDouble`, разумеется.

```
<local:ContentViewerOfDouble ItemsCollection="..."/>
```

Comment: я понял твою мысль, но смотри, я при нажатии на определенную кнопку достаю из базы например List<User> чтобы отобразить список в UserControl , понятное дело мне нужен будет конвертер, чтобы конвертировать в  ObservableCollection<T> где T это  User, как в таком случае UserControl будет знать что ему передали именно User  или что то другое?

Comment: @VitaliiMatviienko: Очевидно, кастомную логику нужно перенести в `ContentViewerGeneric<T>`. По нажатию кнопки пусть вызывается абстрактная (или, если XAML не умеет работать с абстрактными классами, просто то виртуальная) функция.

Comment: @VitaliiMatviienko: А почему не MVVM? Там этой проблемы вовсе не было бы, т. к. VM уж знает нужный тип данных.

Comment: Извени что сразу не написал, имненно с MVVM и работю, я так понимаю для UserControl нужна своя ViewModel?

Comment: @VitaliiMatviienko: Ну как бы да, VM не помешает. Тогда по нажатию кнопки можно выполнить команду из VM (`<Button Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" ... />`), и логика уйдёт в VM.

Comment: Дело в том что кнопка находится на главном окне, соответственно ее команда в VM главного окна, при нажатии отображается фрейм с Контролом этим, как мой контрол узнает какую кнопку я нажал? Извени я только начинающий программист )

Comment: @VitaliiMatviienko: Ну пусть главная VM знает, какая кнопка нажата, и передаёт нужную информацию в VM контрола, например.